# Run Time for Linear Probing on Hash table

Tags: hashtable

what is the running time (big Oh) for linear probing on insertion, deletion and searching.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Theoretical worst case is O(n) since if you happen to insert all the elements such that they consecutively collide then the last element inserted will have to be put into the table n steps from its original hash position.

You could however calculate the average expected number of steps if you know the distribution of your input elements (possibly assuming random, but of course assumption is the mother...), know the distribution of your hashing function (hopefully uniform, but it depends on the quality of your algorithm), the length of your hash table and the number of elements inserted.

If your hashing function is sufficiently uniform you can calculate the probability of collisions using the birthday problem and from those probabilities calculate expected probing lengths.

Comment: Are you sure? What if you have a collision every single insertion? Then you would have to jump 1 slot, then 2, then 3, .... then n. You'd have 1 + 2 + 3 + ...n which gives you a complexity of O(n^2>, does it not?

Comment: That's what I said, the complexity for the linear probing is O(n) which means O(n) for *every* insertion/deletion/lookup. Thus if you have n insertions then your total complexity is O(n^2)